# Unable to Scan Using Brother MFC-J480DW on a Specific Computer

Tags: usb, printers

I have a Brother MFC-J480DW All-in-One device connected to a Windows 10 computer via USB. At a certain point in time (there was no particular change that might do this that I'm aware of) the scanner feature in the device stopped working using the specific computer it's connected to. When I try to scan by clicking on 'Scan' on the device, it's stuck on "Connecting to PC...", and if I try to scan through the ControlCenter4 program - it just won't open (simply nothing happens whether I click on its EXE or open it through Brother Utilities).

It should be noted:

- The problem is just with the scanner. In the same computer I can use this device to print without a problem.
- I can scan with this device on other computers (for example on another computer with Windows 10)
- I'm not aware of any USB issue in this computer

I tried to reinstall the drivers, I checked and its firmware is the latest, I tried to install the ControlCenter4 Update Tool, I tried to run ControlCenter4 as admin and tried to connect the device to other USB ports on the same computer, nothing changed anything so far.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by opening ControlCenter4 when the device was not connected, set it up and then connect the device and it scans successfully.